# Failing to enable Spring Authorization Server token request with JSON request body

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm working on an OAuth2 authorization server using Spring Authorization Server. I need to support the client credentials flow and I like the client to send the client id and secret in the JSON request body of the POST request.

My configuration is pretty straightforward. It's basically all default settings with a custom `RegisteredClientRepository`:

```java
@Configuration
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(UserRepository repository) {
        return repository;
    }
}
```

The `findByClientId` method in UserRepository looks like this:

```java
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserRepository implements RegisteredClientRepository {
    private final UserDao UserDao;

    @Override
    public RegisteredClient findByClientId(String clientId) {
        return userDao.findByClientId(clientId)
            .map(this::toRegisteredClient)
            .orElse(null);
    }

    private RegisteredClient toRegisteredClient(User user) {
        return RegisteredClient.withId(String.valueOf(user.getId()))
            .clientName(user.getName())
            .clientId(user.getClientId())
            .clientSecret(user.getClientSecret())
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
            .authorizationGrantType(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .scope("TEST")
            .clientSettings(
                ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build()
            )
            .build();
    }
}
```

Assume the client id to be `user` and the secret to be `password`.

Requesting a token using basic authentication works:

```sh
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==" http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token\?grant_type\=client_credentials
```

I can also request a token using request URI parameters:

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token\?grant_type\=client_credentials\&client_id\=user\&client_secret\=password
```

But when I try to send the credentials as JSON in the request body like this I get an HTTP 401 error:

```sh
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": "user", "client_secret": "password"}' http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token
```

Here's what's being logged on the server side:

```
DEBUG 2021-10-18 16:04:31,287 [393-exec-4] FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /oauth2/token
DEBUG 2021-10-18 16:04:31,287 [393-exec-4] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
DEBUG 2021-10-18 16:04:31,287 [393-exec-4] AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
DEBUG 2021-10-18 16:04:31,288 [393-exec-4] FilterSecurityInterceptor - Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /oauth2/token] with attributes [authenticated]
DEBUG 2021-10-18 16:04:31,288 [393-exec-4] HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
DEBUG 2021-10-18 16:04:31,288 [393-exec-4] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

How do I make this to work?

Also, why does the Spring Authorization Server support sending client credentials as request URI parameters? [Section 2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-2.3) of the OAuth 2.1 specifications specifically state that request URI parameters must not be used as this is deemed insecure.

Comment: can you please supply the debug logs for the server.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I added the server logs that I get when it gives me an HTTP 401

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an `AuthenticationConverter` to your client authentication configuration, like so:

```java
   @Bean
   @Order(1)
   public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer =
            new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<>();
      RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer
            .getEndpointsMatcher();
      authorizationServerConfigurer.clientAuthentication((clientAuth) -> 
            clientAuth.authenticationConverter(myCustomAuthenticationConverter()) // provide your auth converter
      );

//    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http); the code above is copied from here

      http
            .requestMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                  authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
            .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);

      return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
   }
```

Comment: I see how this would work. To me this seems like a workaround for something that should be default behavior.

Comment: I didn't see this clearly in the documentation.

You can always talk to the creators of the project. Please submit an issue in [the repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues) to get clarification about your question, it may even become a new feature :)

Answer (score 0):

1 - setup ability to call with POST body

```
  @Bean
  public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
... (here your configs)
.clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
```

2. Send POST request with url encoded params and get token as result:

[image]